# Duplicate icons after macOS Sierra upgrade and failed aol login

Tags: macos

I just upgraded to macOS Sierra and now have duplicate google chrome icons on my docking station (one works the other doesnt) and when I try to access my aol email it says log in failed although the password is correct.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly happens when you press on "not working" chrome icon? Are you trying to access your email via mail app?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! In general, we ask that you only ask about one issue per question — your AOL problem seems like it's probably entirely unrelated to your Google Chrome issue, so I'd recommend that you edit this question to only be about one of them, and ask the other separately.